# Python FLASK Return KeyboardIntrupt

Tags: python, flask, web-development-server

I created a route for Flask which executes a python script "Voice_Recorder.py". This script starts recording a wav file. To stop recording and saving the file I need to pass a keyboard interrupt. Is it possible to pass a keyboard interrupt from the frontend to my flask backend?

```
**PY FILE**
  **@app.route('/record/',methods=['POST'])
  def record():
    import Voice_Recorder.py  
    return'done'** 

****HTML FILE**
  **center><button> <a href="/record/">Start recoring!</a></button></center>****
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You cannot. Flask is on the Backend and the Frontend is running in a browser, potentially on any other PC / Mobile etc.

Also, it seems that importing the script **Voice_Recorder.py ** is a blocking operation - that blocks the dev server totally and would prevent you from sending any commands to it. In real world production servers (gunicorn etc) that does not happen, but then there are running several processes so one proce is stuck running your script, while the others cannot prevent it from doing so.

Suggestion:

Your Flask Server should have two routes record and stop_record, your website needs two buttons to expose that. Record should probably start the voice_recorder using subprocess ( [How to execute a program or call a system command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/how-to-execute-a-program-or-call-a-system-command) ) while stop_record needs to send a keyboard command to that script OR write a text file somewhere that Voice Commands.py listens for and shuts down on its own.

There are other solutions, but given the level of your question I am fairly sure they are too complicated for now.

Comment: Thanks if I have record and stop record in a separate python script as functions  do I need to import all their libraries too when I import the functions.

Comment: Importing, no - but you'll need to install them

Answer (score 0):

You can make a use of something called [pynput](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/) :

```
  pip install pynput
```

This will help to detect any key press. “pynput.keyboard” contains classes for controlling and monitoring the keyboard.

For example for pressing "Space bar"

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

keyboard = Controller()

# Press and release space
keyboard.press(Key.space)
keyboard.release(Key.space)
```

Ful doc  [here](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html)